# Replacing a 6 V LED backlight with two 3 V LED backlights

Tags: led-strip, current-limiting, tv, backlight, tcl

I have a 65" TCL TV which have backlight problem and I have another 60" TCL TV with broken screen. Now when I opened both TV to swap with LED backlighting strips, and I and I noticed the 60" TCL is fitted with 6 SMD with 3 V LED and 65" TCL is fitted with 8 SMD with 6 V LED which has one LED flickering (which  is faulty and I want to change it ), but I have only 3 V LED available. So now what should I do? Put the resistor with 3V LED or connect two 3V LED to make it work in series connection with 6 V LED?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please draw a schematic of what you have.

Comment: Have a look i just did :)

Comment: Better, but still unclear. 6 V LEDs as such does not exist. Are there two LEDs in series in some kind of module? How many do you plan to string together before and after? What’s the current rating on the LEDs? What’s the open circuit voltage of the old versus new driver? What’s the drive current if new versus old driver?

Comment: @winny there are leds with multiple chip, quite common for phosphor leds.

Comment: @Damien So basically a module.

Comment: @winny they are referred as LEDs, even if they contain multiple die. Example: https://www.ledsmagazine.com/leds-ssl-design/article/14204410/packaged-led-news-samsung-amps-color-lumileds-amps-performance

Comment: @Damien Strange. OP haven’t been online for some time and it’s unclear if he can just string two in series to make up for the Vf difference.

Comment: His question is quite confusing